# BIOS and Windows cannot detect CDROM device

Tags: windows, drivers, bios, optical-drive, compact-disc

I have a `HL-DT-ST RW/DVD GCC-4521B` dvdrom device and a big problem.

Some days ago everything worked fine. A friend installed some software and then the drives in winxp has been marked as corrupt. I uninstalled the software, but still corrupt drives. The next step I have done was running the current software `GCC-4521B101(E).exe`. When I ran this software again, the drives was automatically updated, but still marked as corrupt (in the Device Manager), even if I did a reboot.

And then the big mistake: once more I tried to run this software, but during the update process, the machine restarted and boom! The DVDROM device doesn't work anymore. The led doesn't blink and if I push the eject button, nothing happens. Also bios and winxp doesn't recognize the optical drive.

Then I plugged an other optical drive and it worked, but my old drive seems to be dead.

So, what happened and how to solve this problem? Please help.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you where updating the firmware on the CDROM device using GCC-4521B101(E).exe, try running that again, if it fails your device has been bricked.

Comment: I have tried to run it again, but the software doesn't recognize the device anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's broken and you have to dispose it ...
If the Bios doesn't detect it it is very likely that the firmware can't adress it again